# Selenium: Unknown error: session deleted because of page crash?

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to load a page with selenium in a loop, it gets to around the 300th item and then throws this exception.

The culprit seems to be this line

```
_selenium.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

So I did a quick google and tried all of the solutions, either they didn't relate to me (docker) or they didn't work.

Here is the exception

```
Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
   at StressTestSelenium.Browser.BrowserHandler.Visit(String url) in /home/ash/Desktop/StressTestSelenium/StressTestSelenium/Browser/BrowserHandler.cs:line 33
   at StressTestSelenium.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/ash/Desktop/StressTestSelenium/StressTestSelenium/Program.cs:line 24
```

It gives no indiciation to what has happened, the browser instance closes straight away.

Here is a minimal example of my code

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
// chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");

chromeOptions.AddArgument("--user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36\"");
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--incognito");

var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
service.EnableVerboseLogging = false;

var _selenium = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);

foreach (var url in repository.Links)
{
    _selenium.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem while running selenium on my vps. After 5 hours i found that, too much unclosed process try to use the driver. try ti kill them all. I didn't see that a crash left an open session of driver

```
pkill -f chrome*
```